# some man pages not found

Tags: manpage

I had fedora a couple of years back and I saw the man pages for the following there:

- `unistd.h`
- `sys/types.h`
- standard typedefs (suffixed by `_t`), etc.

I tried  `man unistd` But it didn't find it.
I think those pages are not there in Ubuntu
Although `man stdio` works.

So

- if Ubuntu doesn't have 'em please tell me how to download them
- And what is the command for viewing standard typedef man page ie man page for size_t, pid_t, off_t, clock_t etc.

I tried `man stddef` but not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the manpages-posix-dev package

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev
man unistd.h
```